# IIS serving corrupted MSI

Tags: iis, web-services, windows-xp, virtual-directory

I am trying to put an .msi for download in a virtual directory setup with IIS.

The download works fine but when I try and install the .msi, it says it is missing a _cabinet file.

Me and a coworker had this issue will the installer downloaded fine & ran correctly on another coworker's machine.

Am I missing anything?

Is it a better approach to send the .msi as a byte[] via a webservice and assemble it on the client side?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the MSI is corrupt? MSI files have a self-checksum  that's verified by the windows installer, if there is corruption a different error is displayed.

I would compare a hash of a failing one with that of one that works, if they are the same the problem is with the way the MSI was compiled.

Comment: On other machine, the IIS is not serving the .msi at all. It has no problems serving text files and .CAB files. any clues?